# Create String from Array Javascrpit Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an Array `[[9,222,3],[9,222,4],[9,333,1],[9,333,2],[9,444,1]]` whare first element is static **secound element is main number** and **third element is sub-number**

I want to create string that contain main number forward by underscore "_" and its sub numbers then Slash and continue..

solution look like **222_3_4/333_1_2/444_1**

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain the logic in detail? For example, how does `[9,222,3],[9,222,4],[9,333,1] `become `222_3_4`

Comment: ok, it is a good thing that the problem has been solved. If there is still a problem next time, it is better to add some examples and logic, which can speed up the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't explain the logic, but here is an example that will give you a good starting point for what you need and is similar to what I've understood.

```js
let arrData = [
  [9, 222, 3],
  [9, 222, 4],
  [9, 333, 1],
  [9, 333, 2],
  [9, 444, 1]
].map((item) => {
  return `${item[1]}_${item[2]}_${item[0]}`;
}).join('/');

console.log(arrData);
```